# Conditional formatting if date between multiple ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got a calendar view and a list of dates with some values. I would like to conditionally show a different color for a given date if that date is in range and the status of it is N. So for statuses 0, 1, and 2 I would like to have different colors in the calendar.

I've tried with `=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A9<=C2:C5)*(A9>=B2:B5)),"Y","N")` but it seems that it does not work with dates.

So it looks like this, and I would like to make the calendar to have colors as in column C.

[Here is the link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DMkNPEb02LMYPPiGNzZUAiZTgotOkndeNJZCIPvucnw/edit#gid=513281584).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional formatting.

You shoould put 2 conditions connected with AND for each period

[image]

My spreadsheet is now set to polish so please forgive me.
Mark your calendar view and Use conditional formatting.
Use custom formula and write:

```
=and($a$2<=f2,$b$2>=f2)
```

Next rule will be:

```
=and($a$3<=f2, $b$3>=f2)
```

and so on

for the first period

Comment: I forgive you, my motther tongue is polish too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your formula should work. You just need to correct the usage/format of it.

Instead of using comma(,) as delimiter of parameters in IF. Use semicolon(;).

This formula works fine on my end.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A9<=$C$2:$C$5)*(A9>=$B$2:$B$5));"Y";"N")
```

[image]